# Automatic line wrapping in rrdtool

Tags: rrdtool

I have a graph made using rrdtool, but the label in the legend is too long, so it gets cut off with ellipses:

[image]

Is there a setting that can be set somewhere to have it use line wrapping in the legend, rather than cutting it off?

Answer (score 1):

Labels in rrdtool can not linewrap.